# Adding Layouts to a LinearLayout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I have a few CryptoCurrencies. They are stored inside a List and now I want to show them on the screen. My idea was to just add a LinearLayout to a layout for each coin I have. Here is my LiveCoinPrice.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="#edf0f4">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/CoinPriceLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#edf0f4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCoinName"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="CoinName"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCoinPrice"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="CoinPrice"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code I tried:

```
InflatedCoinPriceLayout = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LiveCoinPrice, null);
CoinPriceLayout = InflatedCoinPriceLayout.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.CoinPriceLayout);
LiveCoinName = InflatedCoinPriceLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCoinName);
LiveCoinPrice = InflatedCoinPriceLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCoinPrice);
```

And then inside the function where I get the coins I do this:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var coin in coinList)
{
    index += 1;
    LiveCoinName.Text = coin.Coin;
    LiveCoinPrice.Text = coin.Price.ToString();
    CoinPriceLayout.AddView(InflatedCoinPriceLayout, index);
}
```

But this gives me this error on the last line:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I only got 3 coins!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a function call is invoked by a Java application, a stack frame is allocated on the call stack. The stack frame contains the parameters of the invoked method, its local parameters, and the return address of the method. The return address denotes the execution point from which, the program execution shall continue after the invoked method returns. If there is no space for a new stack frame then, the StackOverflowError is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM)

I guess your code  in effect is working like a for each loop without a break condition.
The simplest solution is to carefully inspect the stack trace and detect the repeating pattern of line numbers. These line numbers indicate the code being recursively called. Once you detect these lines, you must carefully inspect your code and understand why the recursion never terminates.

Comment: But I can see that it only hits the last line once!?

Comment: this is weird because stackOverflowError is throwm when there is a lot of stack ! please inspect your code carefully to see what it called recursively

Comment: I found it... I was using a piece of code that wasn't necessary!

Comment: this is great , glad i helped you